# What does JQuery do with randomly generated callback name for JSONP?

Tags: jsonp

so since Ajax generates something like this for the request

```
callback=jQuery19104342058659531176
```

and in the end server returns

```
jQuery19104342058659531176(data)
```

what does it call if jQuery19104342058659531176() function is (obviously) not defined?

I understand it will go to *success/error* handler, but dont really get the purpose of the callback then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fact, jQuery will invoke the callback, then invoke success/error.
If you omit "jsonpCallback", then jQuery will invoke the default one deined by jQuery. the source code is in jsonp.js:

```
window[ callbackName ] = function() {
    responseContainer = arguments;
};
```